# Calling an Angular function from Google Map API InfoWindow

Tags: angular, google-maps

Here is my code

```
addMarker(){
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<button (click)="showJob()">show job</button>' 
    });

    const myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.features[i].latitude, this.features[i].longitude);
    const Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        icon: this.icons[this.features[i].type].icon,
        map: this.map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: this.features[i].title
    });

    Marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(this.map, Marker);
    });

}


showJob(){
    alert("showJobs");

}
```

I want to call method `showJob()` on click of show job button on infowindow but it's not working.

Comment: What's your error?

Comment: i am unable to call function showJob()

Comment: How unable to call? What happens? Is there an error in the console? Does nothing happen? Does your computer explode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`showJob`event is defined in Angular2 component but info window html is not part of components template, that's the reason why `showJob` could not be triggered.

In this scenario `showJob` event could be bound to info window like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', () => {
  const el = document.querySelector('button');
  el.addEventListener('click', (event) => this.showJob(event));
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HIVIpB?p=preview)